# ¿Por qué mi programa me pide un valor más que ni siquiera ocupa el programa?

Tags: c

muy buenas, espero me puedan ayudar con mi programa, tengo un problema con el mismo. El programa trata de resolver sistemas de ecuaciones de congruencia con 3 ecuaciones, es decir, ecuaciones de la forma x=a(mod b), x=c(mod d) y x=e(mod f) y que me coloque los dies primeros valores de la solución.

El problema que tengo es que, al momento de compilar el programa me pide las tres ecuaciones y luego me pide introducir un valor más que ni siquiera hace nada con él, es como si pidiera cuatro ecuaciones pero sólo toma en cuenta las primeras tres.

Aquí está mi programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Programa que calcula la solucion al sistema de residuos de 3 ecuaciones

int SDR(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;

    return SDR(b, a % b);
}

int MCM(int sdr, int b[], int n)
{
    int total = 1;

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        total *= b[k];

    return total/sdr;
}

int evaluacion(int a[], int b[], int n)
{
    int c = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        c *= b[k];

    int sdr = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        sdr = SDR(sdr, b[k]);

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)                        // Esta parte de aqui nos determinará si el sistema tiene o no solucion
    {
        if ((a[k] % 2 == 1) && (b[k] % 2 == 0))
        {
            for (int j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
                if ((a[j] % 2 == 0) && (b[j] % 2 == 0))
                    return -1;      
        }
    }

    int mcm = MCM(sdr, b, n);

    for (int k = 0; k < mcm; k++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (k % b[j] != a[j])
                break;
        int s;
        if (j == n)
        {
            printf("La solucion al sistema dado es: x=%d(mod %d) \n", k, c);
            
            printf("Los dies valores menores que satisfacen el sistema de residuos son: \n");
        
            for (int i=0; i<=9; ++i)
            {
            s = k + c*i;
            
            printf("x%d=%d \n",i,s);
            }
        
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    printf("Introduzca las tres ecuaciones de la forma x=a(mod b) \n");
    int a[n], b[n];

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        fscanf(stdin, "x=%d(mod %d)\n", &a[i], &b[i]);

    int ret = evaluacion(a, b, n);

    if (ret == -1)
        printf("El sistema de ecuaciones dado no tiene solucion.");
}
```

Aquí les agrego una imagen para ser más explícito a lo que me refiero, en rojo puse que prácticamente puedo escribir lo que sea pero el programa no lo tomará en cuenta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es por tu variable int n = 3; estas haciendo un ciclo de 0 a 3 lo cual son 4 ciclos, cambialo a n=2; y problema resuelto.

Comment: @rpaillao, justo pensé en eso, pero cuando coloco n=2 ahora sí hace los 3 ciclos, pero me arroja una solución erronea al sistema, colocando las mismas ecuaciones que puse en la imagen me arroja: x=10(mod 24).

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el código hace lo que quieres? Porque acabo de probarlo y solo almacena el primer par de valores. https://tio.run/##dVDLasMwELz7K5YUB4m4xWkotNjusdBvSHvQy6nAloolg0nJt7srKS5JS/ewGs2uZlYrbg9CzPONNqIbpYLaeant3cdzdkV1mv/mBm0Ogcu08dAzbQjNvjLACISBBnZVvH5ip2/J6tX4wcrxKBh0zIEflAMlRia0NQhRtWPQ2qFnMDWM9FYCp/BmVrT6kWV7814Ax5y4XvVOecIKKAtw@qhsSxilV0V@WeShGKvoBCRoahy1rEDXBtNmQ9MnYosTzLQkrMQUsJqaXMaxcklxrALWbK9xnDXH4@wZIoLTPy5Qwx@fZUMT9uQSFg90SAYX@mfZ5cVLWs9pnqfmIb57otnUPEa4LQPelukS8H3CO/oN

Comment: @Mateo, sí, justo por eso coloqué la imagen que es la solución correcta a ese sistema (puedes comprobarlo con lápiz y papel). El único problema que hallo es que pide un salto de más al compilar.

Comment: tal vez tienes algún archivo de compilación con problemas, elimina los ejecutables y .obj que pudiesen haber, yo lo compile y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwleZ.png

Comment: @rpaillao, a ver deja lo intento, lo hiciste ya compilando con n=2 y las mismas ecuaciones, ¿no?, me refiero a que con n=2 el sistema se resolvió igual de correcto.

Comment: exacto , compilado con n=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probando un poco descubrí que el problema parece ser el salto de línea en el `scanf`.

Al quitarlo, `scanf` funciona como corresponde pero deja un salto de línea en la entrada.

Por lo tanto debes eliminar ese carácter, con `getc(stdin)`.

El código te queda algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    printf("Introduzca las tres ecuaciones de la forma x=a(mod b) \n");
    int a[n], b[n];
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
    memset(b, 0, sizeof(b));

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        fscanf(stdin, "x=%d(mod %d)", &a[i], &b[i]);
        getc(stdin);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("x = %d (mod %d)\n", a[i], b[i]);
    }
}
```

[Pruébalo aquí](https://tio.run/##dVDBbsMgDL3zFVamVKCyKdVUaVOS3fcN3Q4OkAwpgSkQKerUb8@AtFO7aRyM/d7Dz1jcd0Isy502op@kgsp5qe3Dxwu5gXrd/MZGbbqIEW08DKgNZeSLQDgRMFDDY5nKz6D0Lc1ejR@tnI4CoUcHflQOlJhQaGtCGrr2CK0dB4S5RjpYCQ2DN5Ox8qctHsw7hybEFRvU4JSnyKHg4PRR2ZYiYzdkc002kUxscAIae@owalGCrkwI2y1bP5EkTqBpaVyJ4ZDNdS7TWLlkGYcNHnQYZtOE6@wYT6e8WJ@cwdM/flDBH8fLruagySVc3MISOKx2V24nclqWud4n1TMjc/2U0l0R812xFox8Aw)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo modifiqué con lo que mencionas y ya, quedó listo.

Comment: Sabía que era por el salto de línea pero mi oxidadísimo C no me dio pa encontrar la solución. Probé usando sólo scanf y %c para ignorar el fin de línea al comienzo, cambié el formato %d por %i... pero nunca me dio. Buena respuesta :)