# Por que no me permite ingresar palabras la funcion gets

Tags: c

estoy trabajando en un codigo donde quiero agregar texto (palabras o frases) a un archivo txt que ya existe pero quiero preguntar al usuario en que categoria desea agregar las palabras, existen tres, las cuales son facil, medio y dificil.

Entonces el usuario decide a que archivo se le agregara lo que desee, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

// Prototipo de la funcion

void agregar_palabra();

int main()
{
    agregar_palabra();

    return 0;
} 

// Estructura de la funcion

void agregar_palabra()
{
    int opcion_agregar;
    printf("\nEn que dificultad desea agregar palabras: \n");
    printf("\n 1. Facil");
    printf("\n 2. Medio");
    printf("\n 3. Dificil");
    printf("\n\n Ingrese una opcion: ");
    scanf("%i",&opcion_agregar);

    if(opcion_agregar == 1)
    {
        FILE *fp_facil = fopen("facil.txt", "a");
        char palabra_ingresada_facil[25];
        printf("Introduce la palabra para agregar al archivo: ");
        gets(palabra_ingresada_facil);
        fprintf(fp_facil, "\n"); 
        fputs(palabra_ingresada_facil, fp_facil);
        fclose(fp_facil);
    }

    if(opcion_agregar == 2)
    { 

        FILE *fp_medio = fopen("medio.txt", "a");
        char palabra_ingresada_media[50];
        printf("Introduce la palabra para agregar al archivo: ");
        gets(palabra_ingresada_media);
        fprintf(fp_medio, "\n"); 
        fputs(palabra_ingresada_media, fp_medio);
        fclose(fp_medio);

    }

    if(opcion_agregar == 3)
    {

        FILE *fp_dificil = fopen("dificil.txt", "a");
        char palabra_ingresada_dificil[100];
        printf("Introduce la palabra para agregar al archivo: ");
        gets(palabra_ingresada_dificil);
        fprintf(fp_dificil, "\n"); 
        fputs(palabra_ingresada_dificil, fp_dificil);
        fclose(fp_dificil);

    }  

}
```

El problema surge que si me muestra el menu donde puedo seleccionar el archivo al que quiero agregar las palabras, pero luego no me permite agregar las palabras solo se genera el salto de linea en el archivo txt. He intentado realizarlo de varias maneras pero no resulta, me podrian ayudar por favor?

Esto es lo que me arroja la terminar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un problema común. `scanf` lee hasta el último dígito y no borra el salto de línea. Debes consumirlo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mi programa me pide un valor más que ni siquiera ocupa el programa?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/538425/por-qu%c3%a9-mi-programa-me-pide-un-valor-m%c3%a1s-que-ni-siquiera-ocupa-el-programa)

Answer (score 0):

Trata de purgar tu teclado ya que muchas veces se queda guardado el `"\n"`, con la función `fflush()` puedes hacerlo. También puedes usar la función `fgets` para leer los datos

Comment: ... El usuario no usa la función ffush(), usa scanf, por lo que la culpa esta vez no es de ffush()

Comment: Entonces puede ocupar el fgets, en vez del gets. Para poder escribir directamente en el archivo, junto al fflush para que no tenga algun inconveniente